# I can Pause ImageView.animation() but I can't Resume

Tags: android-animation

anyone can help me on how to resume ImageView.animation()? Based on my code bellow I can Pause animation but I can Resume.

```
pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
    pause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            pause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            pause_release.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pause_release.startAnimation(in);
            //ant 1
            walking_1.stop();
            ant_play_1.animate().setListener(null);
            ant_play_1.animate().cancel();
            ant_play_1.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
    pause_release = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause_release);
    pause_release.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pause_release.startAnimation(out);
            pause_release.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //ant 1
            walking_1.start();
            ant_play_1.animate().start();
            ant_play_1.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
```

How to modify my code to make it can Resume onClick?

Comment: So is it the ant_play_1 that doesn't resume? or does the walking_1 also not resume?

Comment: Dear Whitney, the ant_play_1 doesn't resume, and walking_1 resume as usual.

Comment: The cancel killed the animation, so there is no way to resume it. So in order to start your animation again, you need to define a new animation based on where-ever your animation currently is. You could extend the ViewPropertyAnimator class and create your own pause and resume methods to keep your other code neat. This could take a bit of time to do. Easiest thing I can see, but might not suit your purpose would be to switch to use a value animator or an object animator which had methods pause and resume added in API 19.

Comment: @Whitney thank you very much for your advise. I will do best to create pause and resume method. Again thanks you.